# php/mysql - form: How to keep the value of first search after second search?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am using the value of search form **Director1** to auto input in the value of "director_id_1" in the form **CompanyDirectors**, it is working.

However, if I use search form **Director2** to auto input in the value of "director_id_2", it is working but meanwhile the value of "director_id_1" will be empty again.

So, how can I keep the auto input value of "director_id_1" after search **Director2** ???

The below code is saved in the same page: Director.php

```js
<h2> Company Director(s) - Input</h2>

<hr style="border: 1px dotted #2c1294;">

<form name="Director1" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
<input type="text" name="QueryDirector1" />
<input type="submit" name="DirectorName1" value="Search Name of Director 1 to input ID" />
</form>

<form name="Director2" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
<input type="text" name="QueryDirector2" />
<input type="submit" name="DirectorName2" value="Search Name of Director 2 to input ID" />
</form>
 
<hr style="border: 1px dotted #2c1294;">


<form name="CompanyDirectors" method="post" action="Director_insert.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
<b>ID of Director 1:</b>
<input type="number" name="director_id_1" required="required" value="<?php echo $director_id_1; ?>" >

<br>
<b>ID of Director 2:</b>
<input type="number" name="director_id_2" required="required" value="<?php echo $director_id_2; ?>" >

<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Thank you very much for your help & support first !

Comment: I'm afraid I can't follow your question, at all.  Is this a snippet out of a bigger script?  What do you mean by "auto input"?

Comment: Can you show the php code used for getting the value of the id used

Answer (score 0):

If your question (which I find very hard to understand) is:

> I want anything already submitted on the first form (Director 1) to be maintained upon submission of the second form (Director 2), and vice versa.  How could I achieve this?

Then my answer would be use *sessions* or *the database* for *persistence*.

**If** I am understanding your question correctly, you do not understand that HTTP requests are (by nature) stateless.  In other words: when you submit any form data, it is processed server-side and then **ceases to exist**.  The "state" then disappears.

You could cache the submitted data temporarily in a `$_SESSION[...]` variable, or you could store it into the database (and retrieve it back out) or use HTML5 storage in the browser or do something less elegant like use hidden HTML inputs in the second form.  (Or just use one form.)

Some useful links:

- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp
- http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol

So for example:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['DirectorName1'])) {
   $_SESSION['directors'][1]['name'] = $_POST['DirectorName1'];
}
if (isset($_POST['DirectorName2'])) {
   $_SESSION['directors'][2]['name'] = $_POST['DirectorName2'];
}
```

Then print the values from `$_SESSION` rather than `$director_id_1` etc.

It's hard to help without a full copy of your code.